# Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.common.base

Tags: java, deployment, liferay-7, orika

I am trying to add an external library to Liferay - the Orika lib.

I have added the Gradle dependency in build.gradle like this:

```
compileInclude group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.5.4'
```

I am using compile Include in order the module to also have the dependency attached to it.

**The lib is working great locally** - I have tested it with a main method inside the class, but when I deploy to Portal I receive the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: <YourModuleName> [2755]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.common.base_ [Sanitized]
```

This seems to be caused by missing libs at the runtime, but what is not so clear is why are these dependencies added at build time if when I run it within `public static main` it works as expected ?
Also, I have checked the libs Gradle downloaded in my Eclipse to see if there is any package with `com.google.commom.base` and I found none.

So, because some other step is done when building, I checked the the MANIFEST.MF in the generated jar (eg. eclipse-workspace<your_project_name>\modules<your_module_name>\build\libs) and then removing the entry `com.google.commom.base` from file. The error dissapeared, but another one occurred:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: <your_module_name> [2755]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.jdi_ [Sanitized]
```

So, the question is - **Why are those dependencies added and how can I drop or satisfy them ?** - given the fact that I do not have them in Eclipse, then I would go for dropping them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my conclusions after some hours spent with this:

For external jars, the `compileInclude` tactic did not behaving as I was expecting - maybe was a good lead, but I went with the steps detailed below.

In my situation, using only `compileOnly` when including the dependency was better.
So, **the first step** - add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compileOnly group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.5.4'
```

In **the second step**, you have to indicate in `bnd.bnd` file the other dependencies the external jar needs. In my case (Orika lib) it needed the following list: commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar,janino-3.0.8.jar,java-sizeof-0.0.5.jar,javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar,paranamer-2.8.jar,@slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar - I have checked the repo details in order to find this out and got the info from there (eg: from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/ma.glasnost.orika/orika-core)). So, what I had to do after adding  to `build.gradle` was to add the following line in `bnd.bnd`:

```
Include-Resource: @orika-core-1.5.4.jar,@commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar,@janino-3.0.8.jar,@java-sizeof-0.0.5.jar,@javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar,@paranamer-2.8.jar,@slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
```

The last step was to exclude the packages the build process is placing in the `MANIFEST.MF` file - I am talking here about the issues that start with `Unresolved requirement ...`. In order to know what it wasn't needed, I deployed multiple times and for each time I have added the required package to the `Import-Package` list (this is another property in `bnd.bnd` file). The final list was:

```
Import-Package: \
  !com.sun.jdi.*,\
  !com.sun.tools.attach,\
  !com.google.common.base,\
  !org.slf4j.impl,\
  *
```

Note: you may find useful to read more about what I have written [here](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies) and [here](https://liferay.dev/ask#/questions/development/re-poi-and-osgi-not-happy-15).